# Is there any way for my discord.py bot to check check for whether a user has a certain permission to use a command?

Tags: python, permissions, discord, discord.py, bots

For example, my bot has server settings, and currently, any user that can send messages can edit the settings. If a user that doesn't have `Manage Server` permissions tries to edit the permissions, I would love to send a similar message to [the one the Dank Memer Bot sends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odx43.png). I've searched around and it seems as though you can only see what permissions your own bot has, but I am not sure. Is there a way for me to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I Googled "python discord.py check user permissions", first result was https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/discord.py+check+if+user+has+permission Seems to be what your looking for.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I've looked at that, but I believe that unfortunately only checks whether the bot itself has certain permissions, not to check if a certain user has certain permissions. :(

Comment: In the discord.py docs, take a look at `Member.roles`, `Member.permissions` and `Role.permissions`. As long as you have some reference to the member (which you should  if you're responding to their message in a Guild), you can reference those to check for the requisite permissions.

Comment: @Stephen Thank you lots! I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I just did

```
# check if someone has certain permissions
def hasPerms(member, perms):
  for role in reversed(member.roles):
    if not perms.is_subset(role.permissions):
        return False
  return True
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For commands,

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.has_permissions(manage_server=True)
```

You can change the `manage_server` to whatever permission you want. The [Discord API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) for this.

Then what you can do is make an error handler. So if the user does not have permission to do this command, it will send a message.

```py
@command.error
async def command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You do not have permission to do this command!')
```

You **MUST** change `command` to whatever command you want the `Manage Server` on.